# How to use AndroidAnnotations on simple java class

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, android-annotations

I have a simple Java class like following, which doesn't extend from anything.

```
public class WeatherPresenter {

    @App
    CrossWeatherApplication application;

    @Background
    public void loadWeather(String city) {

    }

}
```

So, up there, how can i use **AndroidAnnotations** like `@App` and `@Background` on that class ?

Comment: for what do you want to use them? what do they mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AndroidAnnotations, all classes when you use annotations, have to be marked with the corresponding "enhanced component" annotation. In your example, you want to use `@EBean`.

```
@EBean
public class WeatherPresenter {

    @App
    CrossWeatherApplication application;

    @Background
    public void loadWeather(String city) {

    }

}
```

Then you can inject an instance of this bean into your Activity for example:

```
@EActivity
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    @Bean
    WeatherPresenter weatherPresenter;

    @AfterInject
    void afterInject() {
        weatherPresenter.loadWeather("New York");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you refer to the [Android annotations](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki) library, which is made to simplify Android development for Android developers.
There is a link to the documentation